# making a text field read only

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the code below to make the text entry read only but this does not become read only any idea why this could be

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { Readonly = "Readonly"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cont you use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { @readonly = true});
```

or you can use like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly"});
```

Comment: See edit now I have seen that not "Readonly" it should be "readonly"

Answer (score 0):

try textboxfor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @readonly = true})
```

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlHelper `EditorFor` do not have overloads that take HTML attributes.

Instead of `EditorFor` go with `TextBoxFor`

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled",  @readonly = "readonly"})`

hope it helps

Comment: this doesnt work because readonly befoe the equals sign dose not get reconised