# making text field viewable but not editable

Tags: c#, html

I am using the code bellow to allow users to add view the user name as this name is given by the active directory i would like them to see the filed with name added but not able to edit the data any ideas how i would be able to achieve this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

I have also tried the folowwing two methods which do no work both with or with @ anslo with the statment true

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { @disabled ="disabled"})
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545525/making-a-text-field-read-only/15545568#15545568...try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for go [@Html.**`TextBoxFor`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) extension which you can pass an overload:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @readonly = true })
```

Comment: Your question does not explicitly mention the use of `@Html.TextBoxFor` only `@Html.EditorFor`. Please be more concise with what you have tried and not.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 `EditorFor` does not have overloads to pass additional parameters, but you can use `TextBoxFor` instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

In ASP.NET MVC 4 you can pass parameters directly to `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```